# Is there any ways to combine two rows of table into one row using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm, mariadb, django-orm

I have a table which has columns named `measured_time`, `data_type` and `value`.
In `data_type`, there is two types, `temperature` and `humidity`.
I want to combine two rows of data if they have same `measured_time` using `Django ORM`.
I am using `Maria DB`.

Using Raw SQL, The following Query does what I want to.

```sql
SELECT  T1.measured_time, T1.temperature, T2.humidity
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN data_type = 1 then value END as temperature,
CASE WHEN data_type = 2 then value END  as humidity ,
measured_time FROM data_table) as T1,
( SELECT CASE WHEN data_type = 1 then value END as temperature ,
CASE WHEN data_type = 2 then value END  as humidity , 
measured_time FROM data_table) as T2 
WHERE T1.measured_time = T2.measured_time and 
T1.temperature IS NOT null and T2.humidity IS NOT null and 
DATE(T1.measured_time) = '2019-07-01'
```

Original Table

```
| measured_time       | data_type | value |
|---------------------|-----------|-------|
| 2019-07-01-17:27:03 | 1         | 25.24 |
| 2019-07-01-17:27:03 | 2         | 33.22 |
```

Expected Result

```
| measured_time       | temperaure | humidity |
|---------------------|------------|----------|
| 2019-07-01-17:27:03 | 25.24      | 33.22    |
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it and so can't answer in detail, but you can feed a raw SQL query into Django and get the results back through the ORM. Since you have already got the SQL this may be the easiest way to proceed. [Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Yes, there is some ways to use raw sql query. But I wonder there is a way to do it using Django ORM. If there is no, I'm gonna use the raw sql. Thanks.

Comment: You could wrap a queryset with `.order_by("measured_time")` in a Python generator, which would let you look ahead to see if the next object returned has the same time, and if so `yield` just one object with the merged data and throw the look-ahead result away. I don't know any way to do it as a queryset alone, and could cause grief if somebody then did a `.save()` on the merged object.